# F# passing null reference to ref parameter

Tags: f#, nullreferenceexception

I am using a third party API that rather clumsily makes use of ref parameters to produce outputs. Personally I really hate this design of an API but it's what I have available to me right now. I've had to hide the datatypes of the API slightly due to proprietary code but this should be irrelevant to the problem at hand.

Anyway in C# I can pass a null reference as a ref parameter successfully as follows:

```
            IDataType tl = null;
            bool success = api.myFunction(ref tl);
```

However in F# the following will not work

```
    let mutable tl : IDataType = null //null reference assignment in F#
    let success = api.myFunction(&tl) //& means ref in F#
```

It returns a null reference exception error. No such error is returned in C#.

Has anyone experiences this before? I am thinking it must be a bug in the API itself which is relatively ancient design.

**Edit: This should be closed, I believe the answer does not lie in the F# code but in the API as it's already a number of known bugs similar to this.

Comment: Did you check if tupled use make a difference: `let (success,tl) = api.myFunction()`?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean, the myFunction method takes the ref parameter as an input and returns a boolean not a tuple.

Comment: I think Gene means the way F# calls `out` parameters, but here it is `ref`.

Comment: But isn't `tl` having `[<out>]` attribute? See [Passing by Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233213.aspx) as a guide.

Comment: tl has no attributes, the API is third party and I cannot change it. The code let (a, b) = api.myFunction(&tl) throws a compile error that the type a' * b' was expected but myFunction returns bool.

Comment: is it defined like this: `bool myFunction(out IDataType tl)` or like this: `bool myFunction(ref IDataType tl)` ?

Comment: It is defined as myFunction(ref IDatatype tl). In fact there is one other parameter I missed for simplicities sake. The definition is bool myFunction(int IDnumber, ref IDataType x). This shouldn't matter as the tuple return form is working for every other function i try e.g. the DateTime.TryParse method.

Comment: @RichardTodd That does matter.  The tupled form only works for out parameters.  If you're using a `ref` parameter then the tupled form is not an option.

Comment: OK, please do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @RichardTodd: Does it hurt to initialize it to some non-null value?

Comment: Unfortunately I tried initializing to a type that implements the IDataType interface then did a cast back such as let tl : IDataType = new DataType() :> IDataType, then passed this in as the ref parameter. Strangley i still get a nullreference exception doing this - even though in the debugger I can quite clearly see the value has been initialized to not null.

Comment: @RichardTodd: Something else is going on. I'd be willing to bet that your F# and C# examples compile to the same IL.

Comment: Guys I have to thank you all for this, I believe this simply has to be a .NET versioning or something similar. It wouldn't be the first bug in the API like this I've found, it seems very sensitive to .NET versioning.

Comment: @RichardTodd So post us some IL!

Answer (score 5):

Quick and dirty prototyping of your API in C#

```
namespace API
{
    public interface IDataType { void Hi(); }

    public class API: IDataType {
        public void Hi() { System.Console.WriteLine("Hi!"); }

        public bool MyFunction(ref IDataType iface) {
            iface = new API();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

and then using it from F# exactly your way while staying within the same CLR:

```
let mutable iface : API.IDataType = null
if API.API().MyFunction(&iface) then iface.Hi()
```

works without any problem.

So, indeed, your problem is specific to your given API and has nothing to do with the form of its use from F#.

Comment: What I've done is create a wrapper in C# for some of the method calls to this API. Not ideal but means I can still use this API from F#.

Comment: And if you're wrapping original API you may slightly beautify it applying auto-tupled pattern by putting `public bool MyFunction(out IDataType iface)` into C# wrapper and then using as F# one-liner `let (success, iface) = API.API().MyFunction()`
getting rid of interface reference declaration and initialization altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Using a ref cell is also an option here. Does this work?

```
let tl = ref null 
let success = api.myFunction(tl)
```

Comment: I think you meant "let tl = ref"

Comment: Hi Daniel, as mentioned I think we've tried everything here so the only remaining solution is to look at the IL code. I'm confident there's nothing wrong with the F# code any of us have come up with here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the API being compiled in .NET 2.0 which works fine under C# but not F#.